# Python changing the values of my variables

Tags: python, simulation

I am running a simulation for a concert in which I am generating the amount of time each fan spends in front of the stage before going to do something else (buy food, drinks or go to the restroom). However the time the time i set for them is not the time that is used in the countdown till they leave to do something else.

While doing the countdown I received an error saying i couldn't use the operand `+=` for a NoneType and an int and after changing how the stay was assigned I realized that many of the stay times had been changed.

`Fan` class code

```
class Fan:
    stay = 0
    def __init__(self, gender):
        self.gender = gender
```

This code creates a fan, calculates how long they will stay in front of the stage and them adds them to the stage front area

```
   for i in range(200):
       x = random.randint(1,10)
       if x <= 7:
           f = Fan("f")
           f.stay = stage.calcstay()
           stage.addfan(f)
           print(i,": ",f.stay)
       else:
           f = Fan("m")
           f.stay = stage.calcstay()
           stage.addfan(f)
           print(i,": ",f.stay)
```

This is where the function to countdown the time the fans stay in front of the stage. (literally the next bit of code)

```
for x in range(360):
    stagefunction()
```

This is the `stagefunction()` method:

```
def stagefunction():
    if len(stage.fans) > 0:
        for i in range(len(stage.fans)):
            print(i,": ",stage.fans[i].stay)
            stage.fans[i].stay += -1
            if  stage.fans[i].stay <= 0:
                movefromstage(i)
            stage.TTS += 1
    return
```

I expected `stagefunction()` would be called multiple times each time reducing the amount of time left until each fan in the stage front area by 1 and removing those who aren't supposed to stay any longer. However I cannot even get through `stagefunction()` even once, because the stay time changes and usually around the early 190's a value is changed to a `NoneType`

Comment: can you show your `Fan` class code?

Comment: This is crying out for a Minimal, *Complete*, and Verifiable example.

Comment: @alec935 I've added it

Comment: @OmariLawrence Thank you! I added an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`stay` is a `class variable`, not an `instance variable`. This means that the value of `stay` is universal to all instances of the class, and if you want to change it, you must change it from the class and not an instance.

To define an `instance variable`, put it in your `__init__()` function